# Solution to "mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource" in PHP

Tags: php, database, registration

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Problemas contectando a la base de datos");
mysql_select_db($db_base, $conexion) or die ("Problemas en la seleccion de datos");
$consulta = "insert into cliente(Nombre, Apellido, Usuario, contrasena, nacimiento, sexo, direccion, telefono, celular, perfil, estado) values('$nombre', '$apellido', '$usuario', '$contrasena', '$nacimiento', $genero, '$direccion', $telefono, $celular, '$uploadfile', 1)";
mysql_query($conexion, $consulta) or die ("Problemas en el select".mysql_error());

mysql_close($conexion);
```

This code is executed after the user has registered in my web page

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions and use prepared statements.  Don't put variables directly into your query.

Comment: You are mixing MYSQLI with MYSQL functions. You need "mysqli_query", not "mysql_query" since you used "mysqli_connect"